# Delphi AVIStreamInfo error at work over avifil32.dll

Tags: delphi, avi

There is an application that has been developed 10 years ago under Windows XP under Borland Developer Studio 2006. With a simple application, it reproduced AVI video using Avifil32.dll. Now the application only works under Windows XP, under Windows 7 and above it gives an error (Access Violation) when calling Avifil32.dll.

```
unit dcAVI;

interface
{$I dc.inc}
uses
  Windows, Messages, Graphics, Classes, Controls, mmSystem
  {$IFNDEF D3},SysUtils{$ENDIF};

const
  WM_NEXTFRAME = WM_USER + 1;

  cBufSize = 2048;     {audio buffer size}
  CAheadBuffers = 8;

type
   TAudioPlay = class
   private
     fBufferSize    : integer;
     fAVI           : pointer;
     fSampleSize    : integer;
     fEnd           : integer;
     fPlaying       : boolean;
     fWaveOut       : HWAVEOUT;
     fBegin         : integer;
     fCurrent       : integer;

     function   OpenDevice(W : HWND; pAvi : pointer) : boolean;
     function   FillBuffer : boolean;
   public
     destructor Destroy; override;
     procedure  AudioPlayMessage(W : PWAVEHDR);
     procedure  Stop;
     function   Play(W : HWND; pAvi : Pointer; lStart, lEnd : longint) : boolean;
   end;


  TDCAVIPlayer = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    _dc           : THandle;
    fActive       : boolean;
    fAutoSize     : boolean;
    fCenter       : boolean;
    fFileName     : string;
    fOpen         : boolean;
    fRepetitions  : integer;
    fStartFrame   : integer;
    fStopFrame    : integer;
    fTransparent  : boolean;
    fSkipFrames   : boolean;
    fStretch      : boolean;
    fLength       : integer;
    fFrameWidth   : integer;
    fFrameHeight  : integer;
    fPlaySound    : boolean;

    fOnClose      : TNotifyEvent;
    fOnOpen       : TNotifyEvent;
    fOnStart      : TNotifyEvent;
    fOnStop       : TNotifyEvent;

    favifile      : pointer;
    faudiostream  : pointer;
    fvideostream  : pointer;
    fFrame        : integer;
    fTimer        : THandle;
    fgetframe     : pointer;
    fdrawing      : boolean;
    fdrawcontrol  : integer;
    ftempdc       : THandle;
    ftempbitmap   : THandle;
    foldbitmap    : THandle;
    frepeatcount  : integer;
    fdelay        : integer;
    fbackchanged  : boolean;
    fBlockChanges : boolean;
    faudioplay    : TAudioPlay;
    hdrawdib      : THandle;

    fxstart       : integer;
    fystart       : integer;
    fofs          : integer;
    fxofs         : integer;
    fyofs         : integer;
    fiwidth       : integer;
    fiheight      : integer;

    procedure PlayNextFrame(var Msg : TMessage); message WM_NEXTFRAME;
    procedure SaveBackground;
    procedure AdjustControlsize;
    procedure ShowRect;
    procedure KillTempDC;
    procedure HookWndProc;
    procedure UnHookWndProc;
    procedure MMWOM_DONE(var M:TMessage); message MM_WOM_DONE;
    procedure PlayAudio(startframe, endframe : integer);
    procedure CalcFrameLayout;
    procedure DisplayChange(var Msg : TMessage); message WM_DISPLAYCHANGE;
    procedure ValidateFrameNumber(var val : integer);
    procedure UpdateFrameNumber;
    function  ZOrder : integer;
    procedure StartDrawing;
    procedure DrawFrameToDC(dc : THandle);
  protected
    procedure UpdateOtherAVIPlayers;
    function  PaintDisabled : boolean;
    procedure CreateParams (var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure ShowFrame;
    procedure WMPaint(var Msg : TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Msg : TMessage); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMMove (var Msg : TMessage); message WM_MOVE;
    procedure WMSize (var Msg : TMessage); message WM_SIZE;

    procedure Loaded; override;
    procedure SetActive (val : boolean);   virtual;
    procedure SetAutoSize (val : boolean); overload;
    procedure SetCenter (val : boolean);   virtual;
    procedure SetFileName (val : string);  virtual;
    procedure SetRepetitions (val : integer); virtual;
    procedure SetStartFrame (val : integer);  virtual;
    procedure SetStopFrame (val : integer);   virtual;
    procedure SetTransparent (val : boolean); virtual;
    procedure SetStretch (val : boolean); virtual;
    procedure SetPlaySound(val : boolean); virtual;

    procedure OpenFile; virtual;
    procedure CloseFile; virtual;

    procedure DoOpen; virtual;
    procedure DoClose; virtual;
    procedure DoStart; virtual;
    procedure DoStop; virtual;
  public
    constructor Create (AOwner : TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
    procedure   Play (FromFrame, ToFrame: Word; Count: Integer);
    procedure   Reset;
    procedure   Seek (Frame : integer);
    procedure   Stop;

    property    FrameCount : integer read fLength;
    property    FrameHeight: Integer read FFrameHeight;
    property    FrameWidth : Integer read FFrameWidth;

    property    Open : boolean read fOpen;

  published
    property Active      : boolean read fActive write SetActive default false;
    property AutoSize    : boolean read fAutoSize write SetAutoSize default true;
    property Center      : boolean read fCenter write SetCenter default true;
    property FileName    : string  read fFileName write SetFileName;
    property PlaySound   : boolean read fPlaySound write SetPlaySound default true;
    property Repetitions : integer read fRepetitions write SetRepetitions default 0;
    property StartFrame  : integer read fStartFrame write SetStartFrame default 1;
    property StopFrame   : integer read fStopFrame write SetStopFrame default 0;
    property Stretch     : boolean read fStretch write SetStretch default false;
    property Transparent : boolean read fTransparent write SetTransparent default true;

    property Position : integer read fFrame write Seek;
    
    property OnOpen: TNotifyEvent read fOnOpen write fOnOpen;
    property OnClose: TNotifyEvent read fOnClose write fOnClose;
    property OnStart: TNotifyEvent read fOnStart write fOnStart;
    property OnStop: TNotifyEvent read fOnStop write fOnStop;

    property Align;
    property Color;
    property ParentColor;
    property ParentShowHint;
    property ShowHint;
    property Visible;

    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnClick;
  end;

type
  TAVIStream = record
    fccType    : longint;
    fccHandler : longint;
    dwFlags    : longint;
    dwCaps     : longint;
    wPriority  : word;
    wLanguage  : word;
    dwScale    : longint;
    dwRate     : longint;
    dwStart    : longint;
    dwLength   : longint;
    dwInitialFrames : longint;
    dwSuggestedBufferSize : longint;
    dwQuality    : longint;
    dwSampleSize : longint;
    rcFrame      : TRect;
    dwEditCount  : longint;
    dwFormatChangeCount : longint;
    Name : array [0..64] of char;
  end;

  PAVIStream = ^TAVIStream;

  PAVIFile = pointer;

  TAVIFileInfo = record
    dwMaxBytesPerSec : longint; // max. transfer rate
    dwFlags          : longint; // the ever-present flags
    dwCaps           : longint;
    dwStreams        : longint;
    dwSuggestedBufferSize : longint;

    dwWidth          : longint;
    dwHeight         : longint;

    dwScale          : longint;
    dwRate           : longint; // dwRate / dwScale == samples/second
    dwLength         : longint;

    dwEditCount      : longint;

    szFileType       : array[0..63] of char; // descriptive string for file type?
  end;

  PAVIFileInfo = ^TAVIFileInfo;

  TAVIStreamInfo = record
    fccType               : longint;
    fccHandler            : longint;
    dwFlags               : longint; // Contains AVITF_* flags
    dwCaps                : longint;
    wPriority             : word;
    wLanguage             : word;
    dwScale               : longint;
    dwRate                : longint; // dwRate / dwScale == samples/second
    dwStart               : longint;
    dwLength              : longint; // In units above...
    dwInitialFrames       : longint;
    dwSuggestedBufferSize : longint;
    dwQuality             : longint;
    dwSampleSize          : longint;
    rcFrame               : TRect;
    dwEditCount           : longint;
    dwFormatChangeCount   : longint;
    szName  : array[0..63] of char;
  end;

  PAVIStreamInfo = ^TAVIStreamInfo;


//BeginSkipConst
procedure AVIFileInit; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileInit';

procedure AVIFileExit; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileExit';

function  AVIFileOpen(avifile : pointer; filename : pchar; mode : integer;
                   CLSID : pointer) : integer; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileOpen';

function  AVIFileRelease(avifile : pointer) : longint; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileRelease';

function  AVIFileGetStream(avifile : pointer; avistream : PAVIStream;
                           streamtype : longint; lParam : longint) : integer; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileGetStream';

function  AVIStreamGetFrameOpen(avistream : PAVIStream; bitmapwanted : pointer) : pointer; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamGetFrameOpen';

procedure AVIStreamGetFrameClose(pget : pointer); stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamGetFrameClose';

function  AVIStreamGetFrame(getframe : pointer; position : longint) : pointer; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamGetFrame';

function  AVIStreamOpenFromFile(avistream : PAVIStream; filename : pchar;
                                streamtype : word; lParam : longint;
                                mode : longint; clsid : pointer) : integer; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamOpenFromFile';

procedure AVIStreamRelease(avistream : PAVIStream); stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamRelease';
function  AVIFileInfo(pfile : PAVIFile; pfi : PAVIFileInfo; lSize : longint) : integer; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileInfo';

function  AVIStreamInfo(pstream : PAVIStream; psi : PAVISTREAMINFO; lsize : longint) : integer; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamInfo';
function  AVIStreamRead(pavi : PAVIStream; lStart, lSamples : longint;
                        lpBuffer : pointer; cbBuffer : longint;
                        plBytes,  plSamples : pointer) : integer; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamRead';

function  AVIStreamReadFormat(pavi : PAVIStream; lPos : longint;
                              lpFormat : pointer; lpcbFormat : pointer) : integer; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamReadFormat';

function  AVIStreamBeginStreaming(pavi : PAVIStream; lStart, lEnd, lRate : longint) : integer; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamBeginStreaming';
function  AVIStreamEndStreaming(pavi : PAVIStream) : integer; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamEndStreaming';
function  AVIStreamStart(pavi : PAVIStream) : longint; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamStart';
function  AVIStreamLength(pavi: PAVIStream) : longint; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamLength';
function  AVIStreamSampleToTime(pavi : PAVIStream; lSample : longint) : longint; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamSampleToTime';
function  AVIStreamTimeToSample(pavi : PAVIStream; Time : longint) : longint; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamTimeToSample';

function  DrawDIBOpen : THandle; stdcall; external 'msvfw32.dll' name 'DrawDibOpen';
procedure DrawDIBClose (h : THandle); stdcall; external 'msvfw32.dll' name 'DrawDibClose';
procedure DrawDibDraw (hdib, dc : THandle; xDst, yDst, dxDst, dyDst : integer;
                       lpbi, lpBits : pointer; xSrc, ySrc, dxSrc, dySrc, wFlags : integer); stdcall; external 'msvfw32.dll' name 'DrawDibDraw';
//EndSkipConst

const
  streamtypeAUDIO : longint = $73647561;
  streamtypeVIDEO : longint = $73646976;

  AVISTREAMREAD_CONVENIENT  = -1;

  DDF_HALFTONE = $1000;


constructor TDCAVIPlayer.Create (AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  width := 100;
  height := 50;

  fAutoSize := true;
  fCenter := true;
  fStartFrame := 1;
  fTransparent := true;
  fSkipFrames := true;
  fAutoSize := true;
  fBackChanged := true;
  fblockchanges := true;
  fPlaySound := true;

  AVIFileInit;
  faudioplay := TAudioPlay.Create;
  HookWndProc;
  hdrawdib := DrawDIBOpen;
end;

{------------------------------------------------------------------}

destructor TDCAVIPlayer.Destroy;
begin
  Stop;
  UnHookWndProc;
  DrawDIBClose(hdrawdib);
  KillTempDC;
  CloseFile;
  faudioplay.Free;
  AVIFileExit;
  inherited Destroy;
end;



procedure TDCAVIPlayer.Play (FromFrame, ToFrame: Word; Count: Integer);
var
  info   : TAVIStreamInfo;
  ainfo  : TAVIStreamInfo;
begin
  Stop;
  if not Assigned(fvideostream) then
    exit;

  fFrame := FromFrame;
  fStartFrame := FromFrame;
  fStopFrame := ToFrame;
  frepeatCount := Count;
  AVIStreamInfo(fvideostream, @info, sizeof(info));
  fdelay := MulDiv(info.dwScale, 1000, info.dwRate);
  DoStart;
  fActive := true;
  if Assigned(faudiostream) then
    begin
      AVIStreamInfo(fvideostream, @ainfo, sizeof(info));
      PlayAudio(fFrame, fStopFrame);
    end;

  fTimer := timeSetEvent(fdelay, 0, @Timer, integer(self), TIME_PERIODIC);
end;
```

> --------------------------- Debugger Exception Notification
> --------------------------- Project Kolonka.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 78FA7061 in
> module 'avifil32.dll'. Read of address FEEEFEFE'.

Swears on the line:
AVIStreamInfo(fvideostream, @info, sizeof(info));

I tried to remake AVIStreamInfo under AVIStreamInfoW , but nothing has changed. There is an assumption that the fact is that the system has become 64 bit, or has changed AVIFIL32 after Windows XP. Due to the lack of experience, the idea ran out, I ask for help

**addition**

fvideostream and faudiostream announced at the beginning. Yes, using BDS 2006. Thanks for the interesting program API Monitor, now it has become a little clearer in due to the mistake. The same code works on Windows XP, but does not start on Windows 10 x64

[image: Windows XP SP3 x86]

[image: Windows 10 Pro x64]

```
function  AVIStreamGetFrameOpen(avistream : PAVIStream; bitmapwanted : pointer) : pointer; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamGetFrameOpen';
```

Function:

```
fgetframe := AVIStreamGetFrameOpen(fvideostream, nil);
```

I tried to do this:

```
fgetframe := AVIStreamGetFrameOpen(fvideostream, PBITMAPINFOHEADER(AVIGETFRAMEF_BESTDISPLAYFMT));
```

Why returning is null? It is possible that the sizes of types have changed on Windows X64?

Comment: Make a [mcre]. In the code you showed, `fvideostream` and `faudiostream` are never assigned. You also need to introduce error checking. None of your calls to avifil32 functions checks return values for errors.

Comment: Another option for checking return codes would be to use a Windows API Monitor utility to see all the calls with parameters and results. Useful when you can reproduce the problem and are not sure which calls are having issues.

Comment: You said `I tried to remake AVIStreamInfo under AVIStreamInfoW , but nothing has changed. Are you still develloping your application using `Borland Developer Studio 2006`? If so you should change your code to use `AVIStreamInfoA` since default string type in such old Delphi version is still AnsiString and not WideString as in modern versions. Therefore you should be using AnsiString variations of type structures and methods.